# ASP.NET GridView Sort using DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to sort an ASP.NET GridView using DataTable.Select("", sortExpression)?

I have a regular GridView with AllowSorting="true" and OnSorting="grdEmployees_Sorting".

```
protected void grdEmployees_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = getDataTable();

            var sortExprOrder = e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? " ASC" : " DESC";

            var rows = dt.Select("", string.Format(e.SortExpression + "{0}", sortExprOrder));

            grdEmployees.DataSource = rows;
            grdEmployees.DataBind();
        }
```

Not sure why, but this does not work. The grid shows a bunch of rows with three columns, RowError, RowState, and HasErrors (contains rows with all empty checkboxes).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need select for sorting DataTable.Select is for filtering

This how you sort

```
protected void grdEmployees_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = getDataTable();

            var sortExprOrder = e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? " ASC" : " DESC";

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                e.SortExpression, sortExprOrder);

            grdEmployees.DataSource = dv;
            grdEmployees.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: dt.Select("", sortExpression) returns DataRow[]. Why can't I assign an array of type DataRow to the DataSource of the GridView?

Comment: DataRow holds data in an ItemArray, so if you want to bind DataRow you need to bind collection of ItemArray like GridView1.DataSource = rows.Select(r => r.ItemArray[0]);